# Efficiently loading/caching non-small array from remote source?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm inexperienced at JavaScript, and don't know how to optimize things for my situation.

I've written an autocomplete function using the JQueryUI Autocomplete plugin. The source for the completion is a JSON array, holding a few thousand items, that I load from my same server. This autocomplete will be attached to a search box that will be on every page of my site, so it'll get populated a lot; I don't want to request the same array every time anyone hits any page. The completion depends on database values, so I can't just put the array in static form in the code. However, it doesn't have to be perfectly synced; caching it for some amount of time would be fine.

Right now, I'm loading the array with `$.getJSON`. It seems that using an actual remote source is meant to be an AJAX thing where the server does the actual search itself as you type; I think this is probably overkill given that there are only a few thousand, rather than millions, of items--I don't want to fire a zillion requests every time someone types into the search box.

What is the correct way of handling this? I'm totally unfamiliar with how caching would work in JS, or if there's some built-in way to accomplish a similar thing.

Comment: Is it based on https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache ? Please provide a a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also adjust your minimum text to something like 3 or 4 so that your query will generate smaller levels of results. SQL was designed to do fast queries, JS was not.